# Fenders which fit above rim brakes?

Tags: rim-brake, fenders

My bicycle is pictured below; you may notice that the front tire is wider than stock, and I'm intending on replacing the rear similarly whenever it needs to go.  The challenge is, I want fenders so I don't have to worry about getting caught in the rain, but there is not enough room between the fork and the front tire.  Do I need to find a creative sheet-metal fabricator, or is there an off-the-shelf option of some sort?

[image]

Comment: Nice bike!   Generally V-brakes go around fenders/mudguards so you'd put the guard under the brake's noodle, and below the fork's crown.  Your question is about having insufficient clearance between the tread and those areas because of the larger tyre ?

Comment: Yup, that is exactly it.  And thanks!

Comment: I think you want splash guards rather than fenders.

Comment: Had not heard of splash guards.  Will investigate!

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with off-the-shelf [reacharound brackets.](https://www.rivercitybicycles.com/product/river-city-bicycles-reacharound-fender-brackets-4486.htm) You can also make them out of leftover rack upper stays or other flat strip metal stock.

The idea with them is you take a fender set and cut them where the fork crown and seatstay bridge are, so the fenders don't have to go under them or the brakes. Then you drill holes in the cut off pieces and bolt the brackets on.

[image]

Comment: I suggest finding another source for the solution, the internet site is not reachable (to me) a quick search found these:
https://restoringvintagebicycles.com/tag/reach-around-fender-brackets/

Comment: FYI: Nathan Knutson, concerning your embedded link, Firefox issued this warning: "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead"

Comment: This is a fairly simple bracket - OP could make them from plain strips of metal, or get a steel hardware store shelf bracket and drill/fold/cut as required.   Great idea!